# Errors in Java saving into a File

Tags: java

Currently I am working on something but I don't know if its possible or not.

My problem is that can i save all errors that is displayed in the console and saving it into a text file.?

Also, is it also possible to save the warnings that will be shown.?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    System.err.println("Successfully Printed!");
    PrintStream console = System.err;

    File file = new File("C:\\Users\\USer1\\Documents\\ERRORS\\errors.txt");
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
    PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(fos);
    System.setErr(ps);

    System.err.println("ERRORS FOUND \n \n");



    try {
          int[] x = new int[1];
            x[2] = 5;
            x[1] = 10;
            x[2]=4;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.setErr(console);
```

I have tried this but only 1 error is saved on a text file. Is it possible to capture all errors and also the warning if there is any ( i.e unused variables)

Please keep in mind that I am using Java Language for this .

Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Only 1 error is thrown, so you see only one, x[1] throws error, goes in catch but does not execute [2]. But the best thing if to use a Logger

Comment: Take a few moments and read about logging in Java.  This is the typical way to monitor the state of your application.

Comment: but is it possible to save even the warnings?  compile errors?

Comment: Warnings ? You mean compilation warning ? Well if you write this in java, this won't run during compilation, so no.

Comment: I would suggest you to use a more comprohensive framework like log4j which will allow to you to this and much more.

Answer (score 0):

1) Errors are generally recorded with a logging API instead of using the error output : `System.err`.
It is much simpler and cleaner.
Besides,  assigning a new value to  `System.setErr` in the frame of an application can be very error prone if at a time the statement that re-assigns the original value is not executed.

2) You have to enclose each statement that may throw an exception in a `try/catch` statement to capture all of them.

Extracting the execution of the statements in a method would avoid duplication.

In Java 8, you could write :

```
int[] x = new int[1];
execute(()->x[2] = 5, ()->x[1] = 10, ()->x[2] = 4);

public void execute(Runnable... calls) {
    for (Runnable call : calls) {
        try {
            call.run();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Without Java 8 feature, you will probably use anonymous classes instead of lambdas:

```
int[] x = new int[1];           
execute(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                x[2] = 5;
            }
        },

        new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                x[1] = 10;
            }
        },

        new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                x[2] = 4;
            }
        });
```